# How to set up Composite Action in github actions with action.yml defined in subfolder

Tags: github-actions, github-pages

I am trying to set up a composite action. I have created the action.yml file inside a sub folder `.github/actions/release`  and i am trying  to call the the composite action from a different repo like below

```
name: "Terraform"
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [closed]
    branches:
      - 'main'
env:
  GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    
jobs:
  terraform:
    name: 'Terraform'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Check out code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        
      - name: checkout composite action
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          repository: ppratheesh/terraform-exercise
          path: ./github-shared-workflows
          
         
      - name: release action
        uses: ./github-shared-workflows/.github/actions/release
        with:
          RELEASE_BRANCH: main
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

But the workflow is failing with an error

```
Error: /home/runner/work/terraform-ec2/terraform-ec2/./github-shared-workflows/.github/actions/release/action.yml (Line: 24, Col: 9): Required property is missing: shell
Error: /home/runner/work/terraform-ec2/terraform-ec2/./github-shared-workflows/.github/actions/release/action.yml (Line: 28, Col: 9): Required property is missing: shell
Error: /home/runner/work/terraform-ec2/terraform-ec2/./github-shared-workflows/.github/actions/release/action.yml (Line: 24, Col: 9): Required property is missing: shell
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shared your composite action. But when creating composite actions you have to specify the `shell` for each step. E.g:

```
- name: some step
  shell: bash
  run: echo test
```

Reference: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-composite-action#creating-an-action-metadata-file